# How exactly does strtok work in this instance?

Tags: c, strtok

I have been working on a program that reads a CSV file that contains Names, Age, and GPA values.
The code seems to read through the file fine but I have issues dealing with parsing it as the program is not properly tokenizing values. For some reason it reads the line correctly, then when I try to use strtok to parse it, it only gets the name every time. The CSV is in the form:

```
name1, age1, GPA,
name2, age2, GPA,
```

etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct Student{
    char name[50];
    int age;
    double GPA;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[255];
    struct Student students[100];
    int i = 0;

    if (argc != 2){
        printf("Incorrect input\n\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
            printf("Error: Empty File\n\n");
            exit(-1);
    }

    //takes the next line of the CSV and puts it in the next student
    while(fgets(buffer, 255, fp) != NULL){

        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        strcpy(students[i].name, strtok(buffer, ","));      
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        students[i].age = atoi(strtok(buffer, ","));
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        students[i].GPA = atof(strtok(buffer, ","));
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        i++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        printf("%s, %d, %f\n", students[i].name, students[i].age, students[i].GPA);
    }
}
```

Comment: It repeatedly finds the first token because you don't ever call `strtok()` with NULL as the first argument.  Read the specification for [`strtok_r()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok_r.html) (use this if you're on Unix; use `strtok_s()` on Windows) or plain old (bad old) [`strtok()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html) carefully.  Note that you need to call `strtok()` with NULL for the first argument after the first match to continue searching the original string.  If you pass the start of the buffer, it starts over again.

Comment: I tried to do it that way, but it just gives me the same results as before, but with a segmentation fault at the end instead of getting to the for loop where it prints out the value.

Comment: By including `strtok` within your calls to `atoi` and `atof` you *assume* it will return a pointer to a valid numeric string. What if it returns `NULL` or a pointer to `"bananas"`?

Answer (score 2):

This revision of your code works sensibly (as long as there are no format errors in the data):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Student
{
    char    name[32];
    int     age;
    double  GPA;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[255];
    struct Student students[100];

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s grades-file\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s for reading\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 0; fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL; i++)
    {
        char *token;
        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';
        printf("[%s]\n", buffer);
        strcpy(students[i].name, (token = strtok(buffer, ",")));
        printf("[%s] [%s]\n", buffer, token);
        students[i].age = atoi((token = strtok(NULL, ",")));
        printf("[%s] [%s]\n", buffer, token);
        students[i].GPA = atof((token = strtok(NULL, ",")));
        printf("[%s] [%s]\n", buffer, token);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        printf("%s, %d, %.1f\n", students[j].name, students[j].age, students[j].GPA);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that this code captures the return value from `strtok()` in `token`.  It should check that `token` is not null before calling any other function, so the code as written is rather fragile.  The `strcspn()` call works to zap the newline at the end of the input line, but also works correctly if there is no newline at the end of the line.

Also note how `strtok()` butchers the string.  Once it has isolated the first token, there's a null in place of the delimiter (`,`).  Thereafter, `buffer` doesn't change — hence the code printing `token` too.

Data file:

```
Gavin Thomas, 12, 67.3
Adelie Newman, 13, 89.214
Karen Gibson, 15, 94.599
```

Example output (program `csv17`):

```
$ csv17 data.csv
[Gavin Thomas, 12, 67.3]
[Gavin Thomas] [Gavin Thomas]
[Gavin Thomas] [ 12]
[Gavin Thomas] [ 67.3]
[Adelie Newman, 13, 89.214]
[Adelie Newman] [Adelie Newman]
[Adelie Newman] [ 13]
[Adelie Newman] [ 89.214]
[Karen Gibson, 15, 94.599]
[Karen Gibson] [Karen Gibson]
[Karen Gibson] [ 15]
[Karen Gibson] [ 94.599]
Gavin Thomas, 12, 67.3
Adelie Newman, 13, 89.2
Karen Gibson, 15, 94.6
$
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the manpage for strtok(3) (man 3 strtok):

> The strtok() function breaks a string into a sequence of zero or more
>   nonempty tokens.  On the first call to strtok() the string to be
>   parsed should be specified in str.  In each subsequent call that should
>   parse the same string, str must be NULL.

Also, in case you are wondering how on earth this works:

> A sequence of calls to strtok() that operate on the same string
>   maintains a pointer that determines the point from which to start
>   searching for the next token.

Basically strtok does your book-keeping for you :)

Comment: That makes sense now that I see it, but when I try to use NULL on calls 2 and 3 in each iteration of the loop it does the exact same thing and then give a segmentation fault! Coming from a java background, low level languages are hard :(